# Associative Array sorting value

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I have the following code that should return me an sorted array on the basis of its 'pos' value.

```
local tables = {}

table.insert(tables,{ ['pos']=2, ['name'] = 'C' })
table.insert(tables, {['pos']=1, ['name'] = 'A' })
table.insert(tables,{ ['pos']=30, ['name'] = 'D'} )


function comp(w1,w2)
    if tonumber(w1['pos']) > tonumber(w2['pos']) then
        return true
    end
end

table.sort(tables, comp)

for key,val in pairs(tables) do
    print(val['name'])
end
```

Result is:

D
C
A

Expected (alphabetically sorted by its "pos"):

A,
C,
D

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of `table.sort(table [, comp])` in [PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/19.3.html):

> [comp] This order function receives two arguments and must return true if the
>   first argument should come first in the sorted array

so change the function to:

```
function comp(w1,w2)
    return w1['pos'] < w2['pos']
end
```

note `tonumber` and the if are both unnecessary here.

as @lhf pointed out this can be made simpler still:

```
table.sort(tables, function(w1, w2) return w1.pos < w2.pos end)
```